# Como defino o tamanho e o lugar de componentes?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Criei esse código em java para treinar um pouco e aprender porem não consigo setar o lugar onde o `JComboBox` e o `JTextField` vão aparecer e o tamanho deles como eu faço? Quero deixar eles no meio da janela sem estarem grudados na borda da janela e um no outro e sem que fiquem pegando a janela inteira. `setSize` e `setBounds` não estão funcionando.

Código:

```
/*Biblioteca */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class creator {

public static void main(String args[]){

/*Gera os campos, tela, e configurações */
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTextField texto = new JTextField();
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

/*Cria as opções e configurações do JComboBox */
combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
combo.addItem("opção1");
combo.addItem("opção2");
combo.addItem("opção3");

/*Adiciona as coisas na tela */
panel.add(texto);
panel.add(combo);

/*Configurações da janela*/
frame.setSize(500, 500);        
frame.add(panel);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true); 

}

}
```

Comment: Onde e como você quer posicionar eles?

Comment: tipo no meio da janela com o textfield em primeiro acima do combobox do tamanho que não fique pegando a janela toda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar tamanho, existem os métodos [`setSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize-int-int-), [`setPreferredSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize-java.awt.Dimension-), onde ambos definem as dimensões do componente, porém o segundo o tamanho é apenas relativo. Como a maioria dos containers utilizam [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), eles geralmente costumam se basear no segundo método para definir o tamanho dos componentes, embora alguns também se baseiam nos métodos [`setMaximumSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize-java.awt.Dimension-) e [`setMinimumSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize-java.awt.Dimension-). Estes métodos são herdados da classe [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) e [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

A posição também depende de qual layout está sendo utilizado, cada um possui uma característica de posicionamento, no link acima é apresentado cada um, você pode escolher qual melhor serve para seu objetivo, e até combiná-los, se for necessário.

---

Centralizar os componentes no seu código foi possivel utilizando [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), sem definir posição ou tamanho:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PosicaoDeCompTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            /* Gera os campos, tela, e configurações */
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField texto = new JTextField();
            texto.setColumns(10);
            JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

            /* Cria as opções e configurações do JComboBox */
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            combo.addItem("opção1");
            combo.addItem("opção2");
            combo.addItem("opção3");

            /* Adiciona as coisas na tela */
            panel.add(texto);
            panel.add(combo);

            /* Configurações da janela */
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

}
```

Saida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ressaltando que os gerenciadores cuidam do tamanho do componente na grande maioria das vezes, então não é necessário definir valores fixos para isso, deixe que o layout faça esse trabalho para você.

Comment: setSize e setPreferredSize não estão funcionando.

Comment: @BitsofBytes veja a edição.

Comment: so mais 1 pergunta tem como juntar 2 layouts no mesmo JPanel?

Comment: @BitsofBytes impossivel. Cada painel pode ter apenas um layout.

Comment: ok vlw pela ajuda ^_^

Comment: mals incomodar dnv mais como eu mando o JComboBox para baixo do textField?

Comment: @BitsofBytes recomendo que acesse os links que deixei na pergunta para estudar o funcionamento deste layout. Você está fazendo perguntas que os links explicam. É fundamental saber com que está lidando, se quiser realmente criar boas telas, e para isso, é preciso entender como o layout funciona. Eis o link do tutorial oficial do GridBagLayout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html